# DropBox API file upload

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I followed the example in the Tutorial.
I can upload a file Using:

```
-(IBAction)uploadfile:(id)sender;
{
     NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
     NSString *filename = @"test.png";
     NSString *destDir = @"/Photos";

     [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
     withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
}
```

However; the uploaded file is not a png.
I also  a simple text file and the file again was uploaded but the content of the file is not the original content.

The status of my app in Dropbox is "Development" could this be the reason?

Thank you

....

Changed code to:

```
-(IBAction)uploadfile:(id)sender; 
{ 
    NSString *filename = @"test.png"; 
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
    NSString *localPath = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"test" ofType: @"png"]; 
    NSString *destDir = @"/Photos"; 

    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath]; 
}
```

works perfectly.  Thank you to coneybeare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are uploading a plist, not a png:

```
     NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Try changing the localPath to point to a local image if you want to upload an image.

Comment: Thank you, thought it was just the root path for the bundle, changed as follows and worked perfect.

Comment: Great. Please mark my question as correct if it helped you by checking the green checkbox next to it.

Comment: -(IBAction)uploadfile:(id)sender;
{ 
    NSString *filename = @"test.png";

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *localPath = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"test" ofType: @"png"];
    
    NSString *destDir = @"/Photos";

   [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
}